# How can I format IANA timezone to US Standard timezone

Tags: timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset, moment-timezone, iana

I have a use-case in which I need a user to enter an availability date on the browser (which will be saved in the database in UTC format) for example

```
July 2nd at 6:30PM,
```

i am getting IANA location string using momentjs

```
moment.tz.guess(); //'America/New_York'
```

now when I do the server side rendering, I would like to render the availability date as

```
July 2nd at 6:30 EST 
or 
July 2nd at 6:30 PMT
```

Is there a javascript library to do this for me? how can I convert 'America/New_York' to EST?

worth mentioning it is a reactjs application

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this by momentjs. get the IANA timezone with guess() function as explained above to set the timezone and then format it with as documented in moment documents

```
const date = user input date saved in the database
const z = value of moment.tz.guess() which saved in db
moment(date).tz(z).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A z');
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.